# Same names for components with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it good practice to have same names and selector for components?

For example:

```
products ->
  list.component.html 
  list.component.ts // class ListComponent
users ->
  list.component.html
  list.component.ts // class ListComponent
```

Or better use this style:

```
products ->
  products-list.component.html 
  products-list.component.ts // class ProductsListComponent
users ->
  users-list.component.html
  users-list.component.ts // class UsersListComponent
```

Answer (score 8):

It's not a good practice because let's say you have a `components.module.ts` file where you import all of your component's modules, you will get multiple module imports which shares the same name.

Which renders it impossible to import all of the modules with the same name (unless you use the `as` syntax to "rename" them).

The only scenario I can think of where this is acceptable is for feature modules (pages/routes), where you specify a path to the correct module (if using lazy loading).

But for general components, stay away from it.